# Instantiating a Sequelize connection multiple times in a project: is this a bad idea?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

My goal with this question is to achieve, in a safe and sustainable way, working VS Code intellisense with Sequelize model definitions in my node.js (not typescript) project.

Sequelize models can be constructed

- via hooks, or
- by extending the Model class.

Models created with hooks won't be understood by intellisense, so I'm focused on the latter below.

---

Sequelize model constructors require a configured Sequelize connection instance. There are at least two ways of accomodating this.

## A - Instantiate sequelize next to every model (ie: many times)

One [documented example of model definition](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#extending--a-href-----class-lib-model-js-model-html--model--a-):

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory');

class User extends Model {}

User.init({
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    // allowNull defaults to true
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
  sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
  modelName: 'User' // We need to choose the model name
});
```

In this example, `sequelize` connection is instantiated in the same file alongside the model definition.

We can repeate exactly this in many Model definition files. Each file can then export a Model class which can be used directly by the caller.

Intellisense will understand this setup.

## B - Instantiate sequelize once, and pass it around

Sequelize CLI facilitates the below project structure:

1. Each model definition file exports a *function* which builds the `Model` class. The function accepts the `sequelize` instance as an argument.
2. The `models/index.js` file instantiates `sequelize` -- the only place in the project where this occurs. Every model-definition-function is then called, to which this `sequelize` instance is passed.
3. The resulting models are all exported by `models/index.js`.

It seems intellisense does not understand this, and cannot trace the class methods from these created-by-function exports.

Below is the `User.js` file that Sequelize CLI would create for exactly the same model as the above example:

```js
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class User extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
        }
    }
    User.init(
        {
            firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
            lastName: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: "User"
        }
    );
    return User;
};
```

For the sake of intellisense, I would prefer to (more or less) use the structure evidenced by the **first** example: export classes, **not** functions. I might instantiate `sequelize` in some separate file, but then `require()` that file many times throughout my various model definitions.

Is this a bad idea? Will I unwittingly create some cacophony of competing connections? Do I need to be concerned of any side effects?